# DB2 SQL Interpret a field as other CCSID

Tags: sql, db2

So I have a file on my `AS400` as a result of `DSPJRN` and I want to look at some data in the `JOESD` field which is the after image from the journal of a file. This is defined as char with `CCSID = 65535`. I guess this is because it is the whole record with a mixture of ccsid and numeric fields.

I can use `substr()` to get the actual field from the original file.

In the original file the column is defined `graphic(10) ccsid 13488`. Thats `UCS-2`. 
 If I do `hex(substr(joesd,522,20))` I get a result of  `004100530044...` and so on so I know it's the correct data but I can't get it to display as 'ASD...'

I tried `graphic(substr(joesd,522,20),10,13488)` but it gives an error that `the conversion from ccsid 65535 to 13488 isn't valid`.  I don't want to convert it but interpret it as the other ccsid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GRAPHIC()` doesn't take CCSID as a parm.  The third parm is length according to my 7.1 reference.

What version are you using?

I thought `CAST()` might be a solution, but it doesn't appear to work.

As I see it, one option would be to build a user defined function (UDF) that does the conversion you need; possibly with the `iconv()` API.

The other option, would be to dump the data into a properly formatted file.  I use the DBUJRN utility from DBU.  There's other similar options.  Including an open source [one](http://bender-dv.de/Snippets.html#ANZJRN) (sorry that the description is in German, but google translate does a good enough job to figure out the source to download).

The utilities basically work the same way; you can in fact run through the same process manually.  Try the following:

Step 1 (the DSPJRN you've been doing)

```
DSPJRN <...> OUTFILE(MYLIB/MYJRNOUT)
```

Step 2 - Create a new file with the journal header fields followed by all the fields from your journaled file (MYFILE)

```
CREATE TABLE mylib/mytbl as 
  ( select JOENTL, JOSEQN, JOCODE, JOENTT, JODATE,     
           JOTIME, JOJOB, JOUSER, JONBR, JOPGM, JOOBJ, 
            JOLIB, JOMBR, JOCTRR, JOFLAG, JOCCID,       
           JOINCDAT, JOMINESD, JORES,
           m.*
     from MYLIB/MYJRNOUT , MYLIB/MYFILE m
   ) with no data
```

Step 3 - Copy the data without regard to the format differences..

```
CPYF FROMFILE(MYLIB/MYJRNOUT) TOFILE(MYLIB/MYTBL) MBROPT(*ADD) FMTOPT(*NOCHK)
```

You should end up with data originally in JOESD split into it's appropriate fields.

Note of course that this technique only works for one file at a time.  Also, make sure you're only dumping *RCD entries and you'll probably want to skip the DELETE entries.

Comment: Thanks I have used that to get the information I needed. I was just looking for a shortcut to do it in a single sql query. I did have to use `OUTFILFMT(*TYPE5)` to get a full record into the `JOESD` and that meant mapping some more fields from the journal output.

Comment: @AndyT, glad I could help.  You might consider opening a PMR with IBM.  There should be some way to see UCS-2 or UTF-16 data in the journal.  I suspect they will decide it's not a bug and request you open a DCR.  But it's worth a shot.